# Windows Media Player took control on my play button

Tags: shortcuts, windows-media-player, winamp

I'm using Windows 8 and I want to play / pause my Winamp's songs. However, when I press the Play button, media player launches.

I've changed the preference of Winamp shortcuts and it didn't help...

Answer (score 1):

You have to make Winamp as your default media player.Default Programs is used to choose which programs you want Windows to use by default to open a particular type of file, such as a music file, an image, or a web page. For example, if you have more than one media player installed on your computer, you can choose one of them to be the default player.

To do that:

- Click the Start button to view the Start Menu and then choose the
  Control Panel option.
- From the options choose Programs.
- Under Programs click on Default Programs.
- The windows shows various options. Click on the Set your default
  program.
- A window opens up with the list of all programs available on your
  computer, choose your preferred player.
- Click OK to save changes and Restart.

Check if you can access with the play button. If not then

- Click the Start button to view the Start Menu and then choose the
  Control Panel option.
- From the options choose Programs.
- Under Programs click on Default Programs.
- Click the last option in the Default Programs that is
  `Set program access and computer defaults`. Window opens up with three
  configuration options.Using this you can control access to some
  programs and also set default programs for the computer.
- Customize the configuration settings by clicking on Custom option.
  Window opens up
- Change default media player as **Use my Current Media Player**.

Click OK to save changes and restart.

Hope it helps.